# Build a docker image to publish on Docker Hub

Tags: .net, angular, docker, docker-compose, redis

I have a question about how Docker works.
I currently have a project consisting of 3 services:

- Node (Frontend)
- .NET Core WebApi (Backend)
- Redis (Cache)

I start these three projects through a docker-compose file.
I'm thinking of publishing this project as a Docker image on DockerHub so friends can run it without having to clone the project and install on your nas.
In my mind, I would just need to publish docker-compose and push it to DockerHub. So talking to another developer friend, he told me that I can't publish the docker image like that. He said that I would have to create an image, enter the Linux image, put my 3 services and then publish it as a single image.

Now I'm confused, I don't know much about docker. I know that some images like WordPress already come with the entire environment configured (I don't know if it applies, but I imagine that PHP and Apache/Nginx must be configured).
I want to create a more straight ford image to make the configuration an easier step, just passing some parameters, and I think with docker-compose I can't achieve this, but I do know how to create a full docker image.

Comment: We cannot "push" a compose file. We can, however, push `Dockerfile`s. I suppose that the depending service (redis) is already based on an available image. This means that we would have to publish two images (one for the frontend, one for the backend). Then you can share a `docker-compose.yml` that points to the published images and be done.

Comment: You can build each individual container in your compose file and push them individually. I'm not sure if compose itself has publish support. Can you post an example compose file in a code block?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options for solving that

- The easiest way if you already know how docker compose works, you could upload every program individually to Docker Hub and then send the compose file to github or somewhere else, this way people wouldn't need to build, just run.
- Another possibility is to "merge" containers, that's a little more complex but on the Dockerfile you could merge all the programs together to run in the same container instance. But for this you should need to research more on how to configure and inherit a container.